# Default router: make id persist to all children

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I want to have an `id` to persist through all routes.

e.g. `www.website.com/#/:id/routes`

I have tried to do the following:

```
export default new Router({
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/:id/',
            props: true,
            component: FirstView,
            children: [
                {
                    path: '/',
                    name: 'Second',
                    component: SecondView
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

but i cant get the `:id` to persist. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've specified your nested route path as `/`, which makes the router treat it as the root path instead of prefixing with `/:id` in the parent route.

[Here's a simple demonstration of nesting routes.](http://plnkr.co/edit/S9AVbn?p=preview)